# How to implement SSO for ASP.NET MVC application with ADFS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization

I have an MVC 5 application, i want to be able to implement Single Sign On using ADFS, I have created a Relying Party Trust in AD FS 2.0 server. I want to be able to configure my application users to be authenticated via ADFS. I have done a few researches online, the examples i have found so far assumed the application is hosted on Windows Azure but my application is hosted on a private server.

I have tried following the tutorial found on the link below:

http://www.cloudriven.fi/en/cloud-9-en/how-to-implement-sso-for-asp-net-%20%20%20%20mvc-application-with-adfs/

In the link above the writer didn't specify where to place the below lines of code in the application:

```
var Identity = (ClaimsIdentity)Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity; 

if (Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    foreach (System.Security.Claims.Claim claim in Identity.Claims)
    {                
        if(StringComparer.Ordinal.Equals(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Upn, claim.Type))
        {
            UserLoginID = claim.Value;
        }
        else if (claim.Type.Contains(“samaccountname”))
        {
            SAMAccountName = claim.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I will appreciate assistance from anyone who had worked on any project relating to this

Comment: What the definition of `it didn't work`?

Comment: Here at SO we'll try to help you with a specific problem, not with a complete guidance or general assistance